# FFMPEG input options in rust

Tags: ffmpeg, rust, rtsp

I want to decode rtsp stream like that:`ffplay -max_delay 50000 "rtsp://name:password@1.2.3.4:port"`. So I tried use this crate - https://crates.io/crates/ffmpeg-next , but I succeeded in only non-option receiving data with function `input()` .
Well, I don't understand how to use that option or other options.
Should I use other crate or something else?

Comment: That's going to be the best maintained crate, currently. The docs aren't the greatest, so you're in for some trial and error as you dance with the compiler. Start by looking at the examples for decoding and transcoding. You could look at C++ examples after you understand the analogy and how ffmpeg apis work.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I found the answer. It requires other input.Need to use `input_with_dictionary()`. But before that need to set up the "Dictionary" like that:

```
    let mut name_of_Dictionary = ::ffmpeg::Dictionary::new();
    name_of_Dictionary.set("key", "value");
```

I hope someone will find it helpful.